# Elasticsearch: Filter results in deep aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, facet

I'm trying to retrieve the number of students participating in a combination of sport activities. I've tried using deep aggregation, but I would like to exclude events of the same eventid such that the event is not counted towards the aggregated results if the combination criteria of e.g. 100m and 100m is not met (i.e. both 100m events should have unique eventid). Would this be achievable using elasticsearch?

Mapping:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "events": {
        "type": "nested",
        "include_in_parent": true
    }
  }
}
```

Student data:

```
{
        "name": "Alice"
        "events": [
            {"activity": "400m", "eventid": "4000"},
            {"activity": "800m", "eventid": "8000"},
            {"activity": "100m", "eventid": "1000"},
            {"activity": "100m", "eventid": "1001"}
        ]
},
{
        "name": "Bob"
        "events": [
            {"activity": "100m", "eventid": "1000"},
            {"activity": "400m", "eventid": "4000"}
        ]
}
{
        "name": "Cat"
        "events": [
            {"activity": "400m", "eventid": "4000"},
            {"activity": "400m", "eventid": "4001"}
        ]
}
{
        "name": "Dillian"
        "events": [
            {"activity": "100m", "eventid": "1001"},
            {"activity": "800m", "eventid": "8000"}
        ]
}
```

Query:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
      "activity1": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "events.activity.keyword",
              "size": 5,
              "order": {
                  "_term": "asc"
              }
          },
          "aggregations": {
              "activity2": {
                  "terms": {
                      "field": "events.activity.keyword",
                      "size": 5,
                      "order": {
                          "_term": "asc"
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Incorrect Result:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "activity1": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "100m",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "activity2": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "100m",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "400m",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "800m",
                "doc_count": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "400m",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "activity2": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "100m",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "400m",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "800m",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "800m",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "activity2": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "100m",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "400m",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "800m",
                "doc_count": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Required Result:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "activity1": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "100m",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "activity2": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "100m",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "400m",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "800m",
                "doc_count": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "400m",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "activity2": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "100m",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "400m",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "800m",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "800m",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "activity2": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "100m",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "400m",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "800m",
                "doc_count": 0
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```